# Relational database schema and queries for matchmaking networking event attendees

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am working on an app for matchmaking attendees of a networking event and don't have much experience with relational databases. Every round (10 minutes) attendees are paired up to meet and get to know each other. The app should not match attendees with the same person on subsequent rounds.

Here is the schema that I initially designed:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendees (
    id SERIAL,
    name varchar NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_attendees_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    id SERIAL,
    attendee_id integer NOT NULL,
    partner_id integer NOT NULL,
    has_met boolean DEFAULT false,

    CONSTRAINT pk_matches_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_attendee_id FOREIGN KEY (attendee_id) REFERENCES attendees(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_partner_id FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES attendees(id)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO attendees (name) VALUES
('john'),
('leland'),
('becky'),
('jerome'),
('sarah'),
('ahmed'),
('mike'),
('greg'),
('jessica'),
('latoya'),
('emily'),
('jake');

INSERT INTO matches (attendee_id, partner_id, has_met) VALUES
(1, 4, true),
(4, 1, true),
(3, 2, true),
(2, 3, true),
(5, 6, true),
(6, 5, true),
(7, 9, true),
(9, 7, true),
(5, 1, true),
(1, 5, true),
(7, 3, true),
(3, 7, true),
(2, 6, true),
(6, 2, true),
(8, 3, true),
(3, 8, true);
```

The following query returns all unique matches that can be made without allowing any attendees that have already matched from being paired again on this round:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name
FROM attendees a
CROSS JOIN attendees b
WHERE a.id < b.id
AND b.id NOT IN (
    SELECT m.partner_id
    FROM matches m
    WHERE a.id = m.attendee_id
)
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Within my application, I am able to take the results of the above query and select the pairings for each attendee. Is it possible to modify the query to only return a single result per attendee?

The above approach is likely wrong because the data is not normalized. Am I correct in coming to this conclusion?

I have attempted to redesign the schema to not duplicate data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendees (
    id SERIAL,
    name varchar NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_attendees_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    id SERIAL,
    has_met boolean DEFAULT false,

    CONSTRAINT pk_matches_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participants (
    id SERIAL,
    match_id integer NOT NULL,
    attendee_id integer NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_participants_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_matches_match_id FOREIGN KEY (match_id) REFERENCES matches(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_matches_attendee_id FOREIGN KEY (attendee_id) REFERENCES attendees(id)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO attendees (name) VALUES
('john'),
('leland'),
('becky'),
('jerome'),
('sarah'),
('ahmed'),
('mike'),
('greg'),
('jessica'),
('latoya'),
('emily'),
('jake');

INSERT INTO matches (has_met) VALUES
(true),
(true),
(true),
(true),
(true),
(true);

INSERT INTO participants (match_id, attendee_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 12),
(3, 5),
(3, 7),
(4, 9),
(4, 8),
(5, 11),
(5, 6),
(6, 2),
(6, 10);
```

Is the above database schema correctly designed?

How do I perform a query to return the possible pairings for each round so that there are no repeats? Is it possible to have the database identify the exact pairings to make on each round or is that something that must be done in the application?

Comment: It's not clear what  you want or how you're stuck getting it. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you have two entities:

- `attendees`
- `matches`

The "attendees" might actually be participants; I'm not sure.

You then have a junction table combining them:

- `matchAttendees`

This would have one row per match and per attendee.

If you want to see who has not been matched in previous matches, you would execute a query on these tables.

Comment: I'm lost on what query to make. I've updated the question to mention what I've already tried with the previous schema.